# Databricks Jobs API "INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE" when trying to get job

Tags: databricks, databricks-rest-api, databricks-workflows

I'm just starting to explore the [Databricks API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsGet). I've created a `.netrc` file as described in [this doc](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication.html#netrc) and am able to get the API to work with this for other operations like "list clusters" and "list jobs". But when I try to query details of a particular job, it fails:

```bash
$ curl --netrc -X GET https://<my_workspace>.cloud.databricks.com/api/2.0/jobs/get/?job_id=job-395565384955064-run-12345678

{"error_code":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","message":"Job 0 does not exist."}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job ID should be a numeric identifier while you're providing the job cluster name instead. You need to use first number (`395565384955064`) from that name as a job ID in REST API. Also, remove `/` after `get` - it should be `/api/2.0/jobs/get?job_id=<job-ID>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ curl --netrc -X GET https://<my_workspace>.cloud.databricks.com/api/2.0/jobs/get/?job_id=job-395565384955064-run-12345678
```

In this link, looks like job_name had been mentioned as alphanumeric value instead of job_id. You can find job_id where you can find it .

[image]